# Showing $0\le A \le I$ if and only if $A^2 \le A$ for a self-adjoint operator $A$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I need to show that $0\le A \le I$ if and only if $A^2 \le A$ for a self-adjoint operator $A$.

This problem seems rather simple. It looks like you only need to use the simple defintions, but I'm stuck on it for quite a while.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not so familiar with the topic, so what does $\leq$ mean for operators?

Comment: $A\le B$ means that $\langle Ax,x\rangle \le \langle Bx,x\rangle$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $A:X \to X$ is self-adjoint and that $0 \le A \le I$; that is $$0 \le \langle Ax, x \rangle \le \langle x, x \rangle, \,\,\,\, \text{ for all } x \in X. $$ Since $A$ is self-adjoint and non-negative, there is a self-adjoint, non-negative operator $B$ such that $A = B^2$ (such $B$ is typically referred to as a square root of $A$);  Then for any $y \in X$,we see $$\langle Ay, y\rangle = \langle By, By \rangle \ge \langle ABy, By \rangle = \langle A^2y, y\rangle$$ where the equalities follow since $B$ is self-adjoint and the inequality follows from  the assumption with $x = By$. This shows that $A^2 \le A$.

Now assume that $A:X\to X$ is self-adjoint and that $A^2 \le A$. Then $$0 \le \langle Ax, Ax \rangle = \langle A^2 x, x \rangle \le \langle Ax, x \rangle$$ shows that $0 \le A$. Next, immediately from the above we find that $$\langle A x- A^2x, x \rangle \ge 0 \,\,\,\,\, \implies \,\,\,\,\, \langle A(I - A) x, x \rangle \ge 0, \,\,\,\, \text{ for all } x \in X.$$ Thus for any $x \in X$, \begin{align*} \langle (I - A)x, x \rangle &= \langle (I- A)x, (I-A)x \rangle + \langle (I-A)x, Ax\rangle \\
&=\langle (I- A)x, (I-A)x \rangle + \langle A(I-A)x, x\rangle \ge 0 \end{align*} which shows that $$\langle x,x \rangle \ge \langle Ax, x \rangle$$ and so $A \le I$.